# Byobu type keybindings for tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, byobu

I have been using Byobu for some time now and really enjoying it. But now thinking of moving back to tmux. The reason is  given in the later half of the question. First of all, the question:

#### The Question

How can I get the keybindings of Byobu in tmux standalone. I really like the key-bindings of Byobu. Is their some file in byobu from where I can directly copy the key-bindings and paste into my `tmux.conf` file to be used.

---

#### The Reason of moving from byobu to tmux

The problem is that the tmux-resurrect plugin does not play cool with byobu. When I use the tmux-resurrect plugin to restore my tmux session after restart, it is messed up inside byobu.

The issue is posted here: https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect/issues/61

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).  While I don't know anything about tmux-resurrect, I can point you to the sets of Byobu keybindings, which you can find in:

- /usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux

*Most* of Byobu's keybindings should work just fine in Tmux-without-Byobu.  However, there are a few that depend on some Byobu helper scripts.  You can find those by running:

```
grep BYOBU /usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux
```

And see if any of those are important to you...

Comment: Oh. Wow. Thanks. That is really helpful. I will look at it and in case none of the scripts is important, I guess I will just manually bind the keys.